# Getting length of random list

Tags: python

I have a few functions. My end goal is to pick a random word from the list, split the word into a new list, and then print the length of the selected word.

```
def choose_word():
    for i in range(1):
        words = ['christmas', 'europe', 'icecream', 'america', 'apple', 'hamburger', 'refrigerator', 'dinosaur', 'television']
        word = list(random.choice(words))
        return word

def main():
    print(len(choose_word()))
    print(choose_word())
```

There is a problem, the `len()` is not actually printing the right value. I believe that it may be changing the word every time I call an operation on the randomly selected word. Is there any way to stop this? If I were to run `main()` it would print a number followed by the word, but the number would be incorrect.

Comment: you do realize that your function chooses a different word every time you call it right? so of course calling it twice in a row will give different results, also what is the purpose of `for i in range(1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are calling your function twice, so the first call will give you the length of one random word, and the second time you will get the output of a different word. You should call it just *once*, and store the return of that in a variable, and use *that* variable:

```
def main():
    word = choose_word()
    print(len(word))
    print(word)
```

Furthermore, you seem to be making an unnecessary loop in your `choose_word` function. That is not serving any purpose to your code. The call to `random.choice` is doing all the work of choosing the word for you. No need to do any kind of loop here.

Final code:

```
def choose_word():
    words = ['christmas', 'europe', 'icecream', 'america', 'apple', 'hamburger', 'refrigerator', 'dinosaur', 'television']
    word = list(random.choice(words))
    return word

def main():
    word = choose_word()
    print(len(word))
    print(word)
```

Demo:

```
8
['i', 'c', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'm']
```